# How to levy marquee on the selected text of Android Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, marquee

I have added **Spinner of width**:
`width=this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2;`

in one of the layout in my project. The `spinner` has strings of varied widths, which even wrap up to two lines. Now Since the `spinner width` is definite (half of the screen width), when I select one of the string from the `spinner`, the selected text overlaps the `spinner UI`. 
**How can I apply the marquee effect on the selected text?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have tried adding

```
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

to the selected text's view in your xml file?

[TextView Marquee](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amarqueeRepeatLimit)

Comment: TextView of android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item is used to display the strings under spinner. I have checked this xml. These properties are already set. You can check here:  [link]http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/data/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml.shtml

Comment: I have even coded this also:
`View view=linflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
  TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
  Log.v("EMS1","Found the textview:"+tv);
  tv.setSingleLine();
  tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
  tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);`